# PyQt4 QTableWidget - Filter and modify data from a mySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to PyQt4 and I'm wondering how to filter QTableWidget data pulled from a MySQL database. I was using a QSqlTableModel and I could filter that data easily but I don't like to update the database through a QSqlTableModel. Essentially, I would like the QTableWidget to automatically re-populate as I type search data. I looked at an example in PyQt4 on my Windows machine called "Basic Sort/Filter Model." It does what I want, however, the example uses a QTreeView and I'm using a QTableWidget. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter data you need to wrap your model in a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). The QTableWidget uses a default model that you can't change, so to use the QSortFilterProxyModel you need to use a [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html) instead.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-customsortfiltermodel.html) is a tutorial on how to use the QSortFilterProxyModel.

Comment: Ok, that works well to bring data into a table. Thank you. Is there a way to pass data (a single record) from the QTableView to a QLineEdit?

Comment: The QTableView is just a way to see your data, if you want to obtain the data you can get it from the Model through QTableView::selectedIndexes and QSortFilterProxyModel::index